# Get ID from ROW and include in a linkable result - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code for a search engine. I need to make linkable the results, only in the column `name`, but when I add the code ALL the colums turns as a link.

Here is how the results looks like now: http://postimg.org/image/59y36mih7/

I need to construct the link for the column *name* in this way:

http://www.mysite.com/id, (coma included)

Can you help me how to make the query to get the info from *id* column and make only the results from *name* column clickable? I´m quite lost.

```
<?php



    $MySQLPassword = "*****";   
    $HostName = "***";  
    $UserName = "***";
    $Database = "****";

    mysql_connect($HostName,$UserName,$MySQLPassword)
    or die("ERROR: Could not connect to database!");
    mysql_select_db($Database) or die("cannot select db");


    $default_sort = 'ID';
    $allowed_order = array ('name','description');

    if (!isset ($_GET['order']) || 
        !in_array ($_GET['order'], $allowed_order)) {
        $order = $default_sort;
    } else {
        $order = $_GET['order'];
    }


    if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {

            if(!$_GET['keyword']) {
              die('<p>Please enter a search term.</p>');
        }     





/////////////////////////HERE IS THE BEGINING OF CODE WHERE I THINK SHOULD BE THE PROBLEM ////////////////////////////

    $tables = 'reports';
    $return_fields = 'name organizer_id no_pages publication_date price';
    $check_fields = 'name description';


    $query_text = $_GET['keyword'];

    $clean_query_text =cleanQuery($query_text);

    $newquery=bq_simple ($return_fields, $tables, $check_fields, $clean_query_text);
    $newquery = $newquery . " ORDER BY $order;";

    $result = mysql_query($newquery) or die(mysql_error());


    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($numrows == 0) {
        echo "<H4>No data to display!</H4>";
        exit;
    }
    echo    "<p>Your search '$query_text' returned ".$numrows. " results.</p>\n";
    echo    "<p>Click on the headings to sort.</p>\n";

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
    echo "<TABLE border=1>\n";
    echo "<TR>\n";
    foreach ($row as $heading=>$column) {


        echo "<TD><b>";
        if (in_array ($heading, $allowed_order)) {
            echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?order=$heading&keyword=$query_text\">$heading</a>";
        } else {
            echo $heading;
        }                
        echo "</b></TD>\n";
    }
    echo "</TR>\n";

  /* reset the $result set back to the first row and 
 * display the data */
    mysql_data_seek ($result, 0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
        echo "<TR>\n";
        foreach ($row as $column) {
            echo "<TD><a href='http://mysite.com/(here should be the ID)'>$column</TD>\n";
        }
        echo "</TR>\n";
    }
    echo "</TABLE>\n";
    }

////////////////////////FINISH OF THE CODE WITH PROBLEM ////////////////////////////

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * *  F U N C T I O N S * * * * * * * * * * * */

    function cleanQuery($string)
    {
      $string = trim($string);
      $string = strip_tags($string); // remove any html/javascript.

      if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())  // prevents duplicate backslashes
      {
        $string = stripslashes($string);
      }
      if (phpversion() >= '4.3.0')
      {
        $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
      }
      else
      {
        $string = mysql_escape_string($string);
      }
      return $string;
    }


function bq_handle_shorthand($text) {
    $text = preg_replace("/ \+/", " and ", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/ -/", " not ", $text);
    return $text;
}


function bq_explode_respect_quotes($line) {
        $quote_level = 0;   #keep track if we are in or out of quote-space
        $buffer = "";

        for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($line); $a++) {
                if ($line[$a] == "\"") {
                        $quote_level++;
                        if ($quote_level == 2) { $quote_level = 0; }
                }
                else {
                        if ($line[$a] == " " and $quote_level == 0) {
                                $buffer = $buffer . "~~~~";   #Hackish magic key
                        }
                        else {
                                $buffer = $buffer . $line[$a];
                        }
                }

        }

    $buffer = str_replace("\\", "", $buffer);

        $array = explode("~~~~", $buffer);
        return $array;
}


function bq_make_subquery($fields, $word, $mode) {

    if ($mode == "not") {
        $back = " LIKE '%$word%'))";
    }
    else {
        $back = " LIKE '%$word%')";
    }

    if ($mode == "not") {
        $front = "(NOT (";
        $glue = " LIKE '%$word%' AND ";
    }
    else {
        $front = "(";
        $glue = " LIKE '%$word%' AND ";
    }

    $text = str_replace(" ", $glue, $fields);
    $text = $front . $text . $back;

    return $text;
}



function bq_make_query($fields, $text) {

    $text = strtolower($text);


    $text = bq_handle_shorthand($text);


    $wordarray = bq_explode_respect_quotes($text);

    $buffer = "";
    $output = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i<count($wordarray); $i++) {
        $word = $wordarray[$i];

        if ($word == "and" or $word == "not" and $i > 0) {
            if ($word == "not") {


                $i++;
                if ($i == 1) {   #invalid sql syntax to prefix the first check with and/or/not
                    $buffer = bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "not");
                }
                else {
                    $buffer = " AND " . bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "not");
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($word == "and") {
                    $i++;
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        $buffer = bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "");
                    }
                    else {

                        $buffer = " AND " . bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($word == "and") {
                        $i++;
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            $buffer = bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "");
                        }
                        else {

                            $buffer = " AND " . bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($i == 0) {  # 0 instead of 1 here because there was no conditional word to skip and no $i++;
                $buffer = bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "");
            }
            else {
                $buffer = " AND " . bq_make_subquery($fields, $wordarray[$i], "");
            }
        }
        $output = $output . $buffer;
    }
    return $output;
}



function bq_simple ($return_fields, $tables, $check_fields, $query_text) {


    $return_fields = str_replace(" ", ", ", $return_fields);
    $tables = str_replace(" ", ", ", $tables);


    $query = "SELECT $return_fields FROM $tables WHERE ";
    $query = $query . bq_make_query($check_fields, $query_text);

    #
    # Uncomment to debug
    #

    return $query;
}



?>
```

Comment: Wow... nice stitching job. Now can you get rid of all those `>` chars.?

Comment: Out of the gate, you need to fix the syntax error on line 185: if ($word == "and" or $word == "not" and $i 0) {

Comment: In order to properly indent code for use on SO, I'll give you a super easy way of doing it. Find yourself a copy of Notepad++ and then paste your code inside a new file. Then do CTRL-A to select all, then hit your `tab` key, then copy/paste it here. Easiest way. You'll get the hang of posting code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I put it in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/aspNcN0N

Comment: @ChrisRasco Thanks Chris, however it's the OP's job to post it. Very nice of you though ;-)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply "ChrisRasco @Fred-ii-. I uploaded the code properly formatted now. Regarding the syntax error, I dont get it. The search engine is working properly but I have the problem with the links on the _name_ column. I actually highlited between ///// where the problem can be.

Comment: Your script is still vulnerable to SQL injections: The escaping by `cleanQuery` is later removed by `bq_explode_respect_quotes`. Just try the keyword `"foobar' or '1%'='1"` and you’ll see it.

Comment: And how can I get the data stored in _id_ column, to make the content of the _name_ content linkable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to dig through your code completely, but you should delete your ID column and whatever variable is being used for ID(such as $id) should be formatted like this where your name column is printed.

```
<A HREF=http://mysite.com/"<?PHP echo $id ?>">"<?PHP echo $name ?>"</A>
```

Comment: I hope you don't get downvoted for this, because that won't wash. If it does, it wouldn't have been me.

Comment: This `<A HREF="http://mysite.com/<?PHP echo $id; ?>"><?PHP echo $name; ?></A>` is what you needed to put. Missing `"` after `href` and a fewtoo many  `"`  between your PHP's and before `</A>`